# Adding Sqlite3 to project Error C1853 precompiled header file is from a previous version

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, pch

I am working on a project VS2015 x64 unmanaged cpp
I added sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h to the project and build.  I get this message.

> sqlite Error C1853 precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)

I have read about this and have tried everything I have seen but always the same error.  I changed the project to Not using pre compiled headers - same error and the pch gets regenerated.  I even unloaded and reloaded the project.  I tried to single out the sqlite3.c file and change the properties there but again - same error.  Between each try I clean the project and rebuild.  I am my wits end and have been playing with this for 90 minutes.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you delete the Debug and Release folders and have it rebuild?

Comment: Yes  I did.   I FINALLY looked at the project as I could ego and view the text.   Saw that it still said use precompiled headers.  Manually changed it and it worked.   Must be a visual studio bug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the library - **sqlite3.lib** to your project as an additional dependency.

The library can be created by downloading **Precompiled Binaries for Windows** from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.

This post gives a step by step process on how to include it.
https://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/using-sqlite-in-a-visual-c-application/